# Can I programmatically close dropdown menu displayed by collaspable NavBar?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this Bootstrap enabled HTML markup:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="width: 100%">
    <div class="navbar-header" style="width: 100%">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example- navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span><span
                            class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div style="color: #FFFFFF">
            <div>
                <h4 style="text-indent: 15px; padding: 0px; margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">
                    <span style="color: #FFFFFF;">Title#1</span><span style="color:  #1f7fbb">Motion</span>
                </h4>
                <h4 style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; text-indent: 15px">
                    <small style="font-size: x-small;">Title#2</small>
                </h4>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
             <ul  id="Select1" class="nav navbar-nav">
                 <li class="active"><a href="#">iOS</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">SVN#1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">SVN#2</a></li>
             </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
</nav>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    function test() {
        alert('hi');
        $("#example-navbar-collapse").dropdown('toggle');
    }
</script>
```

Forgive me if this is a basic question but after the User has clicked/touched 'SVN#2' I would like the drop-down to collapse.

This is targeted for small mobile devices.
Can this be done easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```
<li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Click Me</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">SVN#1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">SVN#2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Replace Your Code with this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="width: 100%">
<div class="navbar-header" style="width: 100%">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example- navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span><span
                        class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div style="color: #FFFFFF">
        <div>
            <h4 style="text-indent: 15px; padding: 0px; margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">
                <span style="color: #FFFFFF;">Title#1</span><span style="color:  #1f7fbb">Motion</span>
            </h4>
            <h4 style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; text-indent: 15px">
                <small style="font-size: x-small;">Title#2</small>
            </h4>
         </div>
     </div>

    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Click Me</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">SVN#1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">SVN#2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
 </div>
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong.  The event is raised though .. :(

Comment: @Andrew Simpson understood, make sure you replace "your dropdown" with the dropdown you want to trigger. (I think) in your case it would be this: $("#example-navbar-collapse").dropdown("toggle); Let me know if that works.

Comment: I just updated this answer, give it a try, let me know if that works.

Comment: Hi, thank you for all your time. I did find an answer (below) but I will give this a go as well.

Answer (score 8):

Use the dropdown('toggle') method

```
$("<selector here to select your dropdown>").dropdown('toggle')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. It did not work for me. I could be mis-interpreting what you  meant though. I have amended my question to show the changes you suggested.  thanks

Comment: your selector is wrong. Instead of $("#Select1") use $("#mySelector")

Comment: Hi, yes. That was just a copy and paste error. Updated it now.  It still does not work though :(

Comment: This may work fine in some instances, but with different dropdown display positions, I found adding "data-toggle='dropdown'" on the button to be more reliable.

Comment: In my case (using bootstrap 3), this somehow broke the button that toggled it from working on subsequent presses.

Answer (score 3):

add below line to div tag

### data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropbox"

in HTML like this

```
<div data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropbox"
```

in js/ts

```
$('#dropbox').trigger('click.bs.dropdown');
```

Answer (score -2):

I found putting this in:

```
<a href="#" id="svn1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
```

did the trick.

Hope it helps someone...